# Question from an exam in real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

This question came up in our most recent exam in real analysis 1 course. I have no idea how to answer it but I thought it would be an interesting challenge.

Let $g, f \in \mathbb{P}_n \ (n \in \mathbb{N})$ and suppose that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ the equality $$\int_0^1x^kf(x)dx = \int_0^1x^kg(x)dx  $$ holds, then $f = g$.

Comment: Hint: Use Weierstrass thoorem concerning density of polynomial functions in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but your wording is not good. It should be let $f,g \in \mathbb P_n$ and suppose that for any $k \in \mathbb N_0$... holds, then $f=g$.

Comment: No need for Weierstraß because $p=f-g$ is already a polynomial with $\int_0^1 x^kp(x)dx=0$. Multiplying by the (complex conjugate in the complex case) coeefficients of $p$ and add to get $\int_0^1 |p(x)|^2dx=0$. Finally, use the continuity of the positive function $|p(x)|^2$ to conclude.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I don't think that this is related. It is much simpler as $f,g$ are supposed to be polynomials. But again the wording of the question has to be reworked.

Comment: @Jochen Indeed, as phrased, we are not even being given a *statement* to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the wording suggestion, english isnt my first language.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $h(x) := f(x)-g(x)$, the problem amounts to showing

$$ \left[ \forall \; k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \quad \int_0^1 x^k h(x)  dx = 0 \right] \implies h(x) = 0$$
for any polynomial $h(x)$. The simplest approach is probably to recognize that, writing $h(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, we find
$$ 0 = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \int_0^1 x^k h(x)  dx = \int_0^1 (h(x))^2 dx.$$
This implies $h(x)$ must be zero almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, which forces it (as a polynomial) to be identically zero.